# How is String concatenation working in following

Tags: java, string, concatenation

As per the following [How Java String pool works when String concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037516/how-java-string-pool-works-when-string-concatenation) conversation,

```java
String a = "hello world!";
String b = "hello" + " world!";
boolean compare = (a == b);
```

The `compare` should be true which is correct.
However, I've the following code

```java
String s1 = "This is";
String s2 = " a new String";
String s3 = s1 + s2;
String s4 = "This is a new String";
```

On comparing `System.out.printf("s3 == s4:%s\n", s3 == s4);//always false`
It is always false. My understanding is that on concatenation of `s1` & `s2`, `s3` will create a string in pool and when `s4` is created it will point to the same pool location. But this is not the case. I've tried this with different JDKs including 7, 8 and 14 and the results are consistent.

Comment: "s3 will create a string in pool" no. Runtime-evaluated strings are only added to the pool if you explicitly request it, with `intern()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the behaviour regarding pooling strings is specified in the Java Language Specification (emphasis mine):

> [3.10.5 String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)
>
> [...]
>
> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class `String`. This is because string literals - or, more generally, ***strings that are the values of constant expressions*** (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

Only [constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) of type `String` are pooled. `"This is a new String"`, and `"hello" + " world!"` are constant expressions. The compiler can evaluate these expressions at compile time. `s1 + s2` is not a constant expression.

So when executing `s1 + s2`, a new string *is* created. But note that another string, which just so happens to have the same characters as the new string, is in the string pool, because you used a string literal to initialise `s4`.