# Java String Memory-Address

Tags: java, string, memory-address

Why is the result false？

```
String s1 = "hello";
String s2 = "world";
String s3 = "helloworld";
String s4 = s1+s2;
System.out.println(s3==s4);
```

As I know, there's already one "helloworld" in the constant pool.

Thanks for answering, but what I want to ask is not the difference between "==" and "equals", I just want to make sure `s1+s2;` makes a new String, even though there's already one String Object with value "helloworld" in memory.

Comment: Use .equals() i.e., s3.equals(s4)

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan I think the point is that it isn't pointing to the same string instance. Not that the strings aren't equal in value.

Comment: s4 will create a new String and so == comparison fails. == only works for String literals and not for variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: You probably expect that `String s4 = s1+s2;` gets optimized away at compile-time. But it doesn't, it will still be a statement at run-time. Therefore, you're creating a new `String` there.

Comment: I had the same question earlier. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61588929?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that they all are object instance of class String

```
String s1 = "hello";
String s2 = "world";
String s3 = "helloworld";
```

This creates 3 objects with different values and different memory

```
String s4 = s1+s2;
```

Now you are again creating a new object with same value as s1 and s2 but since its a new object it has different memory.

```
 System.out.println(s3==s4);
```

Now with this line you are trying to compare the values for these 2 objects and in String class the correct way to do it is by using equals() method i.e.,

```
System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));
```

For detailed information please check this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/

Answer (score 0):

`(s3==s4)` - means comparing references, not values. reference `s3` is not the same as reference `s4`. `s3` and `s4` are two different instances of String.
use `equals` for comparing values of objects. override equals for your own classes if it necessary.